# How can we solve this form of the Bessel equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, frobenius-method

By solving: $$t^2 \left(\frac{d^2R}{dt^2}\right)+2t \left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)+(t^2-n)R=0$$

Using the method of Frobenius: $$R(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^{k+m}$$

Gives the indicial equation: $$m^2+m-n=0$$

How can the roots of this indicial equation be used to find the Bessel function solutions to this Bessel equation?

Comment: $m^2+m-n$ isn't an equation, there is no $=$ in it. Then what is it ?

Comment: Check your work closely, Kit.